# Tomcat is deployed to the server, causing memory overflow over time

Tags: java, tomcat8

```
04-Apr-2019 18:10:53.685 WARNING [localhost-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [pool-2-thread-500] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:209)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecuenter code heretor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1006)         java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Tomcat is deployed to the server. Over time, memory overflow occurs. Finally, the entire tomcat is down.

I am using tomcat-8.5.31.

Comment: Which tomcat version you are using ?

Comment: Hello, I am using tomcat-8.5.31, the project is deployed to the server, running for a while, there will be memory overflow, how to solve this problem

Comment: The problem should be with your code and not Tomcat. As the error says, a thread has started and failing to stop.

Comment: Tomcat running server configuration is too low, will not cause memory overflow, I added a thread pool management thread in the code, but the maximum value of the thread pool is 2000, running the server configuration is too low, resulting in memory overflow, will this happen? Happening!

Comment: The output didn't say there is a stackoverflow, it just says there is a thread that can't stop.

Comment: Ok, let me take a closer look, thank you.